# error when deploy to AWS after build using vue3 + vite

Tags: amazon-web-services, vuejs3, vite

First off all excuse the bad english..
Im develop/build using vue3 + vite2.

Deploy the 'dist' folder on AWS EC2 and run the server with nginx.

And when I connect to that page, I get an error that I can't see.

Has anyone ever seen an error like this?

(When build/run locally, it works normally without errors.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a day of suffering, i found that it was  due vueI18n plugin in the vite.config.ts file.

```
import vueI18n from '@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n';
import path from 'path';
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueI18n({
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, './path/to/src/locales/**'),
    }),
  ],
....
```

I don't know for what reason,
When I delete that plugin, it worked fine.

the reason for adding vueI18n plugin is because a warning related to bundle install occurred.

i guess is that the plugin conflicts with vite's build environment.